# Change target framework in Blazor WASM project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, blazor, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2022

I recently created a `Blazor` project using `VS 2022 Preview-Community`. In the beginning of create the project I choose `.Net 5` and the project ran correctly. But when I want change the target framework to `.Net 6`, I got this error while running:

[image]

I have same issue in `VS 2019`. How can I change target framework in `Blazor` projects?

Thank

---

Edit 1)

Nuget installed packages (After change target framework to 6):

[image]

Comment: What changes have you done in your code base?
Have you deleted the nuget cache and .vs folder ?

Comment: I think your problem is the same reported here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/34054.
Try to watch on it.

Another possibilities is to create 2 identical project, one for 5 and one for 6, and compare the code base.

Comment: Just update your NuGet packages. Then it 'just works' .

Comment: @NicolaBiada ".. compare the code base" - that would show a lot of irrelevant changes. They overhauled the templates.

Comment: @NicolaBiada No I didn't. I'll test it

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I restore Nuget packages but nothing changed

Comment: Not "Restore". You need to "Update" them.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: There isn't any update for `.Net 6` :(.

Comment: Yes there are. What does your "installed packages" tab show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the picture:

.net 6 is still in preview so you have to check "[x] Include prereleases"

You will then see that there are 3 updates, to .net6.0.0-preview.*  .

Comment: Thanks. One step forward but when the project ran, just `Loading` message has been shown for a while and nothing happened

Comment: Try again with a new project (.net5 -> .net6) . That should work. Then find the changes you made that now fail.

Comment: Thanks. It seems you work on `Blazor` and have very experience. How can I have `Hot Reload` in my project? I create a project using '.Net 6` but it hasn't this feature and I should stop and start my project for any changes. Thanks